# Why Is this artifact happening when baking AO?

Tags: uv, texture-baking

I'm pretty sure I understand the simple process behind baking but sometimes I have hard times as such because of these weird artifacts.
And topology is on point, all quads, with no overlapping verts or anything :(
[image]

Comment: I think you had a hidden Object, if not can you provide the blend file?

Comment: OMG hahahahaha!!! I figured this out and now that I did i was going back to comment on my own question and already found someone who knew the answer